# ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME

Tags: ros, ros-ip, ros-hostname, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In my understanding according to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME), `ROS_IP` is for the IP address of the host machine where a ROS node runs and `ROS_HOSTNAME` is for a resolvable host name. But I'm confused because an IP address is also a resolvable name(maybe resolved name?). So even when I set an IP address to `ROS_HOSTNAME`, everything works well.

I saw the source codes and found that both are treated almost same([rocpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/roscpp/src/libros/network.cpp#L87), [rospy](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/network.py#L123)).

So my questions are

1. Why are there two environmental variables`ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME`, even though both are treated almost same?
2. Is it better to always use `ROS_HOSTNAME` to avoid network troubles? I've seen some people have troubles because they set both variables and `ROS_IP` doesn't work as they expected.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248415/ros_ip-and-ros_hostname/) by [otamachan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25120/otamachan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-11-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-19**:
As a general comment, whenever I've had ROS networking issues exporting `ROS_HOSTNAME=$ROS_IP` fixes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not an answer, but IMO this is a worthwhile thing to discuss as a possible improvement in `ros_comm`, so I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1251).

The example section in the [NetworkSetup wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Setting_a_name_explicitly) explains when having both variables are useful, but the usecases there don't sound convincing enough to me that we have to have 2 different variables.

If there are actually usecases where separate variables are needed, I/we'd appreciate if you share the story in the linked ticket.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1